# Are you exempt for Kosovo visa if you have a valid UK multi-entry tourist visa?

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens, kosovo

I am an Indian passport holder and have a valid UK multi-entry tourist visa. Am I exempt from the need for a Kosovo visa?

Comment: FWIW this is a useful list of [countries you can travel VISA-FREE with UK visa](https://www.visatraveler.com/blog/travel-countries-visa-free-with-uk-visa/) IIRC Montenegro was on the list until sometime in 2023.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having a multiple entry visa for the UK granted you 15 days visa-free, but this [is not the case anymore](https://ambasadat.net/visas/)

> Citizens of countries to which the Republic of Kosovo applies a visa regime but who have a valid biometric residence permit issued by one of the Schengen Area countries, as well as holders of a valid multi-entry Schengen visa are exempted from the need to obtain Kosovo visa for entry, transit and stay in the territory of the Republic of Kosovo. Their stay within the territory of the Republic of Kosovo is limited to 15 days.

Only Schengen countries are mentioned by exemption, you will need a visa

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you so much. Looks like they removed UK multi entry visa as an exemption.

Answer (score 4):

> Are you exempt for Kosovo visa if you have a valid UK multi entry tourist visa. Cannot find this information.

I will assume you are referencing the information found here:

- [Visa policy of Kosovo - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Kosovo)

> Visa is not required for citizens of any country with a valid multiple entry Schengen visa **or the United Kingdom** or a valid biometric residence permit from a Schengen State **or the UK**. They may stay in Kosovo for a maximum period of 15 days. [3]

The given source (dated 2022-03-18), '[3]', however **does not** list the United Kingdom in the **special categories** chapter of that page. The oldest [Wayback Machine copy from 2022-12-07](https://web.archive.org/web/20221207011615/https://ambasadat.net/visas/) contains the same text as today. I have updated the Wikipedia page, removing the UK reference.

So this claim cannot be confirmed.

---

- [Kosovo Visas - Embassies of the Republic of Kosovo](https://ambasadat.net/visas/)

> **SPECIAL CATEGORIES EXEMPT FROM VISA REQUIREMENTS**
> **The following categories are exempt from the need to obtain a visa:**
>
> - Citizens of countries to which the Republic of Kosovo applies a visa regime but who have a valid biometric residence permit issued by one of the Schengen Area countries, as well as holders of a valid multi-entry Schengen visa are exempted from the need to obtain Kosovo visa for entry, transit and stay in the territory of the Republic of Kosovo. Their stay within the territory of the Republic of Kosovo is limited to 15 days.
> - Citizens of: EU Member States, Schengen Area Member States, Holy See, Principality of Andorra, Principality of Monaco, Republic of San Marino, Republic of Albania, Montenegro, and Republic of Serbia are allowed entry , transit and stay of up to 90 days for a period of six (6) months, with a valid biometric ID card.
>
> ...

Comment: Exactly, so the wikipidea page is not updated. Thank you so much. Very clear now.

Comment: @GauravTaparia Since the oldest wayback copy saved is from 2022-12 one cannot say for sure, but it looks as if it never was true.

Comment: @GauravTaparia I have updated the Wikipedia page, removing the UK reference.

Comment: Ah, noted. Thanks a million

Comment: Did that, thank you